# Adding mobile module to existing wear app still only supports wear devices?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project and in it I have a module for a mobile app `mobile` and a module for a wear os app `wear`. Both apps build and deploy to the emulator as expected but I'm having trouble with the Play Console.

How can I add both the wear and mobile apps to my play store listing so that when a user visits the listing from their phone it installs my mobile app and when they visit it from a watch it installs the wear app?

I have built and published the wear bundle to the Play Store into the Internal Testing track and was able to install and use the app on my watch. I did this using `./gradelew :wear:bundleRelease` and `./gradlew :wear:publishBundle`.

Now I would like to add the mobile module as well in the next release to support mobile devices.

When I try to run `./gradelew bundleRelease` and `./gradlew publishBundle` to build and publish both bundles

I have tried to build just the mobile bundle and publish that and it does seem to work but the supported devices only lists wearable devices and not phones or tablets. I checked and there is no `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />` manifest for the mobile app, there's no reason I can see it would be limited to wearable devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was coming from Manifest Merging.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#merge-manifests

"Merge multiple manifest files
Your APK or Android App Bundle file can contain just one AndroidManifest.xml file, but your Android Studio project may contain several manifest files provided by the main source set, build variants, and imported libraries. When building your app, the Gradle build merges all manifest files into a single manifest file that's packaged into your app.

The manifest merger tool combines all XML elements from each file by following merge heuristics and obeying merge preferences that you have defined with special XML attributes."

I was able to see the merged manifest by clicking the "Merged Manifest" tab along the bottom pane of the window when the manifest for my mobile app was open:

[image]

I right clicked on the line in the manifest and selected "Remove".

This added the following to my manifest:

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

... and now my app is served as expected.